# How does publish() with a selector works in Rx?

Tags: rx-java2

I read and understood how `publish()` works (it returns a `ConnectableObservable` etc). And then I've tried to `publish([selector])`, but there's no any `ConnectableObservable` in the signature of `publish([selector])`. And [that picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/publishConnect.f.png) looks pretty confusing to me.
Where can I read how `publish([selector])` actually works?

UPD: [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-multicasts-secret-760e1a2b176e) this seems legit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this more recent marble diagram could help:

[image: publish(Function)]

It works as if you had a `PublishSubject` that can be transformed as you see fit and the output is the result of those transformations presented as a single `Observable` returned by the function. The difference is from the plain `publish()` is that this `PublishSubject` is created for each individual subscriber so the upstream is only shared locally.

You could think of it as you'd done a deferred regular `publish()` operation:

```java
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1, 5)
    .delaySubscription(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Function<Observable<Integer>, Observable<Integer>> func = o ->
    Observable.merge(o.take(1), o.takeLast(1));

Observable<Integer> forkAndJoin = Observable.defer(() -> {
    // prepare the connection
    ConnectableObservable<Integer> conn = source
        .doOnSubscribe(s -> System.out.println("Subscribed!"))
        .publish();

    // get the transformation for the downstream
    Observable<Integer> result = func.apply(conn);

    // establish the connection
    conn.connect();

    // allow the downstream to subscribe to the result
    return result;
});

forkAndJoin.subscribe(System.out::println);
forkAndJoin.subscribe(System.out::println);
forkAndJoin.subscribe(System.out::println);

Thread.sleep(10000);
```

You should get 3 `Subscribed` printed only, due to those outer `subscribe` calls, but inside in `func` the `o` is consumed twice with different transformations and merged together, yet they don't trigger more `Subscribed` calls.

The actual implementation is a bit more involved in RxJava as it has to defend against disconnected transformations, handle the downstream cancellation propagation as well as backpressure in the `Flowable` version.